# Flex 4 skin in FXG or image which is more efficient?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I need to display the skin as a piano keys which has up and down state.

Compare to a commercial grade music player like NI Kontakt, it doesn't consume over 10% (around 3-5% to be exact) of my CPU when playback a song or I abuse by press the keys repetitively as fast as I can. However, I see my Flex app will use over 10% which is double wasteful. I tried lower the framerate to 20, still doesn't help, how do I use as much as CPU consumption as possible?

For flex skin component (button), I have implement gradient, stroke and BevelFilter effect for up and down state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your app going to be scaled? If not use bitmaps or vectors cached as bitmaps.

Take a look at this article by Aral Balkan

http://aralbalkan.com/759